# How do I make my iFrame scrollable on Mobile?

Tags: css, iframe

I have a problem with an iFrame on my Mobile. When I open the webpage on my mobile there are no scroll bars or even an option to scroll the iFrame.

I've tried several CSS codes but nothing seems to work.

Can somebody help me out?

Cheers,

Comment: Iframe is scrollable by default, if it doesn't work you disabled it.

Comment: Plz, provide the code, so that we can look into it.

Comment: Thanks @cloned that was a very helpful answer!